# Json loop doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, foreach

I have a JSON array and some JavaScript, but the loop doesn't execute.

I can't find the error.

HTML:

```
<div class="rosa" id="Mittelt">
  // place to append
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var url = {"cats": [
        {"id":"1",
            "pictures":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg",
            "picsmall":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"},
        {"id":"2",
            "pictures":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg",
            "picsmall":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg"}
        ]
    };
    var json=url["cats"];
    $(json).each(function(item) {
        console.log(json[0].id);
        item=json[0];
    $('<div class="lulu">' + 
        '<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" data-src="'+item.pictures+'.jpg"/>' +
        '<img class="lora" src="'+item.picsmall+'"/>'+'</div>')
        .appendTo('#Mittelt');
    })
```

CSS:

```
.lulu {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0px);
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}

.lora {
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0px);
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

Here's a link: https://jsfiddle.net/5wyL5azj/2/

Comment: You're overwriting `item` so it always points to the first element: `item=json[0];` Remove that line.

Comment: i tried it on fiddle. but it wasnt the error :-(

Comment: Also change `$(json).each(function(item){` to `$(json).each(function(i, item){`

Comment: @Viktor You made my day :-), thanks. but now i tried with 3 ids, and it stops after the second. can you take a look please? https://jsfiddle.net/5wyL5azj/6/

Comment: That's only due to your CSS styles. If you inspect the rendered HTML with Developer Tools or similar, you can see that all three `div`s and their contents are there.

Comment: @Viktor Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
    (function(i){
       $('<div class="lulu">' + 
          '<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" data-src="'+json[i].pictures+'.jpg"/>' +
          '<img class="lora" src="'+json[i].picsmall+'"/>'+'</div>')
          .appendTo('#Mittelt'); 
    })(i)
 }
```

`item=json[0]` will always point to the first element, and the loop won't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/5wyL5azj/4/

Comment: @Thalavier hmm... i think i have wrote wrong the code.
every id has 2 pictures. and i wourd set with the each loop, for every id a div, with the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually set the `item` variable, it will be set to the next item in the array for you:

```
$(json).each(function(item) {
    console.log(item.id);
    $('<div class="lulu">' + 
        '<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" data-src="'+item.pictures+'.jpg"/>' +
        '<img class="lora" src="'+item.picsmall+'"/>'+'</div>'
    ).appendTo('#Mittelt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters passed into jQuery's each method are `index` followed by the `item`. In your code, *item* refers to the *index* and not the ***item*** itself. Change your each code to something similar to this:

```
var test = function() {
  var url = {"cats": [{"id": 1,"name":"one"},{"id":2,"name":"two"}]};
  var json = url["cats"];
  //json.forEach(function(item){ console.log(item); });  // Native JS for each loop
  $(json).each(function(){ console.log(this); }); // jQuery for each loop
};
```

Of course, the pure JS `for each` is usually faster than jQuery, but that shouldn't matter much in your current scenario

Comment: hmm, can you change the code for me, because i have no idea. :-(